# Wave - Export to PDF

Tags: einstein-analytics

How can i export a wave dashboard as a pdf file?
By default salesforce provides a link to Export as an image but export to pdf is not provided currently.

Comment: Is the dashboard embedded in a visualforce page?

Comment: @cricketlang - No, it is not embedded

Comment: There's no native way to export a wave dashboard as a pdf at this time. You'll also run into issues if it's embedded because the dashboards are just iFrames. You could attempt some sloppy techniques if you embedded it, but I wouldn't recommend it as the quality is pretty poor.

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no Native way you can Download PDF